# How to search array of string in another string in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, string

Firstly, I want to inform that, what I need is the reverse of in_array PHP function.

I need to search all items of array in the string if any of them found, function will return true otherwise return false.

I need the fastest solution to this problem, off course this can be succeeded by iterating the array and using the strpos function.

Any suggestions are welcome.

**Example Data:**

```
$string = 'Alice goes to school every day';

$searchWords = array('basket','school','tree');
```

returns **true**

```
$string = 'Alice goes to school every day';

$searchWords = array('basket','cat','tree');
```

returns **false**

Comment: Well, I don't think you are getting any faster than `strpos()`.

Comment: Disagree with u, @Erisco. Regular expressions will do it and are faster. I just don't know much of it.

Comment: Didn't check the answer by malko before I posted the initial comment.

Comment: @afaolek, I believe it is largely going to depend on the number of search words. For small numbers, I doubt regexp is going to win, unless the string being searched becomes very large and the number of search words is greater than one.

Answer (score 10):

You should try with a preg_match:

```
if (preg_match('/' . implode('|', $searchWords) . '/', $string)) return true;
```

After some comments here a properly escaped solution:

```
function contains($string, Array $search, $caseInsensitive = false) {
    $exp = '/'
        . implode('|', array_map('preg_quote', $search))
        . ($caseInsensitive ? '/i' : '/');
    return preg_match($exp, $string) ? true : false;
}
```

Comment: `$searchWords` should be properly escaped

Comment: Im not going to down vote you as it is a valid answer, but I do think that `preg_match` is pointless when you have functions like `strstr` and `stristr`

Comment: @binaryLV: yes this is just a quick idea to point in the right direction and that should work with the sample code in the question but a more reliable solution must properly escaped the words @RobertPitt, strstr or stristr wouldn't test against multiple strings in a single pass, or i missed something ? If we end to use it in a loop i think that preg_match would be more efficient no ?

Comment: Looping through values (which may mean looping through a whole lot of values) can be very inefficient. Using a regular expression may well be faster than that. But, as always, only profiling will reveal the faster method.

Comment: PCRE are never ever going to be faster than language constructs.

Comment: When since are `strstr` and `stristr` language constructs?

Comment: i was talking specifically about the `foreach` and `if` statement

Comment: @RobertPitt So you're saying using foreach and if is always faster than matching with a regular expression? I'd love to see some benchmarks on that really, because I don't see that happening.

Comment: I had some code that generated HTML with placeholders that had to be replaced with something. At first, I thought that I'll write some quick-and-dirty code with PCRE and then convert it to using "plain string functions" for performance, when I have some time for that. When I did that, it turned out that PCRE did perform at least as good as "plain string functions" in a loop, maybe even better.

Answer (score 3):

If string can be exploded using space following will work:

```
var_dump(array_intersect(explode(' ', $str), $searchWords) != null);
```

#### OUTPUT: for 2 examples you've provided:

```
bool(true)
bool(false)
```

#### Update:

If string cannot be exploded using space character, then use code like this to split string on any **end of word character**:

```
var_dump(array_intersect(preg_split('~\b~', $str), $searchWords) != null);
```

Comment: Sometimes it's not possible to explode using space in my case, but thanks, this is a cool method.

Comment: @WebolizeR In that case you can use `var_dump(array_intersect(preg_split('~\b~', $str), $searchWords) != null);` that will split original string by any end of word character not just space.

Answer (score 3):

```
function searchWords($string,$words)
{
    foreach($words as $word)
    {
        if(stristr($string," " . $word . " ")) //spaces either side to force a word
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

#### Usage:

```
$string = 'Alice goes to school every day';
$searchWords = array('basket','cat','tree');

if(searchWords($string,$searchWords))
{
     //matches
}
```

Also take note that the function [stristr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php) is used to make it **not** case-sensitive

Comment: You might also specify that `$words` must be an array, i.e., `function searchWords($string, array $words) { /* ... */ }`

Comment: Nope, That is only supported in very new releases of PHP, that would just confuse people in my opinion.

Comment: Array type hinting was introduced in PHP 5.1.0 which was released in 24-Nov-2005 - I would not call it a "very new release" in year 2011.

Comment: Hmm That's a good point, I must of been confused with something else along those lines. My Apologies.

Answer (score 3):

As per the example of malko, but with properly escaping the values.

```
function contains( $string, array $search ) {
    return 0 !== preg_match( 
        '/' . implode( '|', preg_quote( $search, '/' ) ) . '/', 
        $string 
    );
}
```

Comment: isn't that what @malko just posted :/

Comment: @Robert yes but this one properly escaped the searched string and is more reliable, i we want to make a "perfect" solution we can add a third parameter $caseInsensitive=false by default that add a 'i' to the end of the regexp to allow searching in a case insensitive manner ie: '/' . implode( '|', preg_quote( $search, '/' ) ) . '/'.($caseInsensitive?'i':'')

Comment: in fact this won't work because preg_quote doesn't handle array as parameter, see my post i've edited your solution a litlle bit

Comment: ayea it should be `implode( '|', array_map(function($e){return preg_quote( $e, '/' );},$search)`

Comment: `Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: preg_quote(): Argument #1 ($str) must be of type string, array given`

Answer (score 1):

There is always debate over what is faster so I thought I'd run some tests using different methods.

**Tests Run:**

1. strpos
2. preg_match with foreach loop
3. preg_match with regex or
4. indexed search with string to explode
5. indexed search as array (string already exploded)

Two sets of tests where run. One on a large text document (114,350 words) and one on a small text document (120 words). Within each set, all tests were run 100 times and then an average was taken. Tests did not ignore case, which doing so would have made them all faster. Test for which the index was searched were pre-indexed. I wrote the code for indexing myself, and I'm sure it was less efficient, but indexing for the large file took 17.92 seconds and for the small file it took 0.001 seconds.

Terms searched for included: gazerbeam (NOT found in the document), legally (found in the document), and target (NOT found in the document).

**Results in seconds to complete a single test, sorted by speed:**

Large File:

1. 0.0000455808639526 (index without explode)
2. 0.0009979915618897 (preg_match using regex or)
3. 0.0011657214164734 (strpos)
4. 0.0023632574081421 (preg_match using foreach loop)
5. 0.0051533532142639 (index with explode)

Small File

1. 0.000003724098205566 (strpos)
2. 0.000005958080291748 (preg_match using regex or)
3. 0.000012607574462891 (preg_match using foreach loop)
4. 0.000021204948425293 (index without explode)
5. 0.000060625076293945 (index with explode)

Notice that strpos is faster than preg_match (using regex or) for small files, but slower for large files. Other factors, such as the number of search terms will of course affect this.

**Algorithms Used:**

```
//strpos
$str = file_get_contents('text.txt');
$t = microtime(true);
foreach ($search as $word) if (strpos($str, $word)) break;
$strpos += microtime(true) - $t;

//preg_match
$str = file_get_contents('text.txt');
$t = microtime(true);
foreach ($search as $word) if (preg_match('/' . preg_quote($word) . '/', $str)) break;
$pregmatch += microtime(true) - $t;

//preg_match (regex or)
$str = file_get_contents('text.txt');
$orstr = preg_quote(implode('|', $search));
$t = microtime(true);
if preg_match('/' . $orstr . '/', $str) {};
$pregmatchor += microtime(true) - $t;

//index with explode
$str = file_get_contents('textindex.txt');
$t = microtime(true);
$ar = explode(" ", $str);
foreach ($search as $word) {
    $start = 0; 
    $end = count($ar);
    do {
        $diff = $end - $start;
        $pos = floor($diff / 2) + $start;
        $temp = $ar[$pos];
        if ($word < $temp) {
            $end = $pos;
        } elseif ($word > $temp) {
            $start = $pos + 1;
        } elseif ($temp == $word) {
            $found = 'true';
            break;
        }
    } while ($diff > 0);
}
$indexwith += microtime(true) - $t;

//index without explode (already in array)
$str = file_get_contents('textindex.txt');
$found = 'false';
$ar = explode(" ", $str);
$t = microtime(true);
foreach ($search as $word) {
    $start = 0; 
    $end = count($ar);
    do {
        $diff = $end - $start;
        $pos = floor($diff / 2) + $start;
        $temp = $ar[$pos];
        if ($word < $temp) {
            $end = $pos;
        } elseif ($word > $temp) {
            $start = $pos + 1;
        } elseif ($temp == $word) {
            $found = 'true';
            break;
        }
    } while ($diff > 0);
}
$indexwithout += microtime(true) - $t;
```

Comment: You forgot to pass `$word` through `preg_quote()`. You also did not test `preg_match()` without `foreach` loop (by passing list of quotted "words" as `word1|word2|word3`).

Comment: Great points. I've taken your suggestions and updated the results above.

Comment: `$orstr = preg_quote(implode('|', $search));` does not look right. Each word should be quoted rather than whole pattern. Replace it with `$orstr = implode('|', array_map('preg_quote', $search)); $orstr = str_replace('/', '\\/', $orstr);`. Second operation is needed for escaping delimiters. It would also be worth doing some tests with different sets of words (e.g., with 2 words and with 5 words).

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$string = 'Alice goes to school every day';
$words = split(" ", $string); 
$searchWords = array('basket','school','tree');

for($x = 0,$l = count($words); $x < $l;) {
        if(in_array($words[$x++], $searchWords)) {
                //....
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below prints the frequency of number of elements found from the array in the string

```
function inString($str, $arr, $matches=false)
    {
        $str = explode(" ", $str);
        $c = 0;
        for($i = 0; $i<count($str); $i++)
        {
            if(in_array($str[$i], $arr) )
            {$c++;if($matches == false)break;}
        }
        return $c;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Below link will help you : just need to customize as you required.

[Check if array element exists in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10137674/check-if-array-element-exists-in-string)

customized:

```
function result_arrayInString($prdterms,208){
  if(arrayInString($prdterms,208)){
      return true;
  }else{
     return false;
  }
}
```

This may be helpful to you.