# Check if array element exists in string

Tags: php, arrays

I thought this would be a simple thing to do with a native php function but i've found a few different, all quite complicated, ways that people have tried to achieve it. What's the most efficient way of checking if a string contains one or more elements in an array? i.e, below - where $data['description'] is a string. Obv the in_array check below breaks because it expects param 2 to be an array

```
$keywords = array(
            'bus',
            'buses',
            'train',
    );

    if (!in_array($keywords, $data['description']))
            continue;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Assuming that the String is a collapsed/delimited list of values

```
function arrayInString( $inArray , $inString , $inDelim=',' ){
  $inStringAsArray = explode( $inDelim , $inString );
  return ( count( array_intersect( $inArray , $inStringAsArray ) )>0 );
}
```

Example 1:

```
arrayInString( array( 'red' , 'blue' ) , 'red,white,orange' , ',' );
// Would return true
// When 'red,white,orange' are split by ',',
// the 'red' element matched the array
```

Example 2:

```
arrayInString( array( 'mouse' , 'cat' ) , 'mouse' );
// Would return true
// When 'mouse' is split by ',' (the default deliminator),
// the 'mouse' element matches the array which contains only 'mouse'
```

### Assuming that the String is plain text, and you are simply looking for instances of the specified words inside it

```
function arrayInString( $inArray , $inString ){
  if( is_array( $inArray ) ){
    foreach( $inArray as $e ){
      if( strpos( $inString , $e )!==false )
        return true;
    }
    return false;
  }else{
    return ( strpos( $inString , $inArray )!==false );
  }
}
```

Example 1:

```
arrayInString( array( 'apple' , 'banana' ) , 'I ate an apple' );
// Would return true
// As 'I ate an apple' contains 'apple'
```

Example 2:

```
arrayInString( array( 'car' , 'bus' ) , 'I was busy' );
// Would return true
// As 'bus' is present in the string, even though it is part of 'busy'
```

Comment: I can't get strpos( $inString , $inArray ) to work. The second parameter can't be an array in strpos. Have you really tested this?

Comment: Hi Olaf, Thanks for the comment. I can't remember what testing I did, as this answer was submitted over 2 years ago. But, I have adjusted the code so that it should now iterate through the array and perform the expected checks.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using regular expressions -

```
if( !preg_match( '/(\b' . implode( '\b|\b', $keywords ) . '\b)/i', $data['description'] )) continue;
```

the result regexp will be `/(\bbus\b|\bbuses\b|\btrain\b)/`

Comment: clean and simple. Exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

## Asssuming whole words and phrases are being searched for

This function will find a (case-insensitive) phrase from an array of phrases within a string. If found, the phrase is reurned and $position returns its index within the string. If not found, it returns FALSE.

```
function findStringFromArray($phrases, $string, &$position) {
    // Reverse sort phrases according to length.
    // This ensures that 'taxi' isn't found when 'taxi cab' exists in the string.
    usort($phrases, create_function('$a,$b',
                                    '$diff=strlen($b)-strlen($a);
                                     return $diff<0?-1:($diff>0?1:0);'));

    // Pad-out the string and convert it to lower-case
    $string = ' '.strtolower($string).' ';

    // Find the phrase
    foreach ($phrases as $key => $value) {
        if (($position = strpos($string, ' '.strtolower($value).' ')) !== FALSE) {
            return $phrases[$key];
        }
    }

    // Not found
    return FALSE;
}
```

To test the function,

```
$wordsAndPhrases = array('taxi', 'bus', 'taxi cab', 'truck', 'coach');
$srch = "The taxi cab was waiting";

if (($found = findStringFromArray($wordsAndPhrases, $srch, $pos)) !== FALSE) {
    echo "'$found' was found in '$srch' at string position $pos.";
}
else {
    echo "None of the search phrases were found in '$srch'.";
}
```

As a matter of interest, the function demonstrates a technique for finding whole words and phrases, so that "bus" is found but not "abuse". Just surround both your haystack and your needle with space:

```
$pos = strpos(" $haystack ", " $needle ")
```