# PHP validate function on each array element

Tags: php, arrays, validation

I want something like

`array_validate('is_string',$arr);`

If the array elements are all strings, then it will return TRUE.
But, if there is/are non-string type in the array, it will return FALSE.

Is there any built-in PHP function that does this?

Comment: use foreach loop and the function is_string()

Comment: @ArmanMalekzade I know it, but is there a more efficient way? Something like array_map or array_filter, but this one validates all of the array elements...

Comment: if you visit the documentation in php.net ... exactly where they describe is_string() function ... in that page there is an example of what you want to do ... so i think there is no built-in function for that ! http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-string.php

Comment: you can use : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10137674/check-if-array-element-exists-in-string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution using [`array_reduce`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php):

```
function array_validate($callable, $arr)
{
  return array_reduce($arr, function($memo, $value) use ($callable){ return $memo === true && call_user_func($callable,$value); }, true);
}

array_validate('is_string', ["John", "doe"]); // True
array_validate('is_string', ["John", "Doe", 94]); // false
```

Also, you could use other callables:

```
array_validate([$object, "method"], ["something"]);
array_validate("is_array", [ [], [] ]); // true
```

Answer (score 0):

Run through array, if a element is not a string return false. If all elements are string it will reach the end off the function and return true.

```
function array_validate($array){
    foreach($array as $arr){
        if(!is_string($arr){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: So, there is no built-in function that does the thing?

Comment: Not that I know off. is_string exists for a string but if you want to check an array you'll have to use a workaround

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in function, but this might work for you:

```
function array_type_of(array $array, $type)
{
    if ('boolean'  === $type ||
        'integer'  === $type ||
        'double'   === $type ||
        'string'   === $type ||
        'array'    === $type ||
        'resource' === $type ||
        'object'   === $type || // for any object
        'NULL'     === $type) {

        foreach ($array as $v) {
            if (gettype($v) !== $type) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    } else {
        foreach ($array as $v) {
            if (!$v instanceof $type) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Use it as:

```
$array = array( /* values */ );

$istype = array_type_of($array, 'boolean');
$istype = array_type_of($array, 'integer');
$istype = array_type_of($array, 'double');
$istype = array_type_of($array, 'string');
$istype = array_type_of($array, 'resource');

$istype = array_type_of($array, 'DateTime');
$istype = array_type_of($array, 'IteratorAggregate');
```