# Search keywords from array in string (PHP)

Tags: php, arrays, string, search, keyword

```
$array_keywords = ('red','blue','green');
$string = "Sometimes I'm happy, Sometimes I'm blue, Sometimes I'm sad";
```

(PHP) Search keywords (from array) in string and print coincidences, in this case desired result should be return "**blue**".

How do I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
$array_keywords = array('red','blue','green');

$string = 'Sometimes I'm happy, Sometimes I'm blue, Sometimes I'm sad';

foreach ($array_keywords as $keys) {
    if (strpos($string, $keys)) {
        echo "Match found"; 
        return true;
    }
}
echo "Not found!";
return false;
```

You can also use [stristr()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stristr.php) and [stripos()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php) to check case-insensitive.

Or you can see [Lucanos answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10137763/5588347)

Answer (score 0):

Check this code,

```
<?php
function strpos_array($haystack, $needles, &$str_return) {

    if ( is_array($needles) ) {
        foreach ($needles as $str) {
            if ( is_array($str) ) {
                $pos = strpos_array($haystack, $str);
            } else {
                $pos = strpos($haystack, $str);
            }

            if ($pos !== FALSE) {
                $str_return[] = $str;
            }
        }
    } else {
        return strpos($haystack, $needles);
    }
}

// Test
$str = [];
$array_keywords = ('red','blue','green');
$string = "Sometimes I'm happy, Sometimes I'm blue, Sometimes I'm sad";

strpos_array($string, $array_keywords,$str_return); 
print_r($str_return);
?>
```

This is advanced [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) code with arrays.

More precise way of doing your requirement is, to get the array if matches more than single element.